# How can i convert this code so i can get the row from list view

Tags: android, listview

I want to be able to fetch a row from a list view and populate textViews in a different activity. I want to be able to do this onclick of an item with the list view..

```
public class CBFilter extends Activity {

    ListView RecipeNames;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    CBDataBaseHelper data;
    SQLiteDatabase data2;
    TextView RecipeText;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        RecipeNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List1);
        RecipeNames.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        RecipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, 0, cursor, null, null);

        data = new CBDataBaseHelper(this);
        data.open();
        cursor = data.query();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = {CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = { R.id.recipeText};


        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
        RecipeNames.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }

    public void CreateNew(View view){

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

How can i convert this code in order to achieve the required functionality.. thanks Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   String string = from[position]);  // this depends on your Adapter ...
   Intent i = new Intent(CheckData.this,ShowData.class);
   i.putExtra("SELECTED", string);
   startActivity(i);
```

i got it from this link , it will be use full for you : 
[Use of SQLite](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/use-of-sqlite/)

Comment: hmmm does this suggest then i will have to create a another class that extends list activity?