# obtain data from list view with click

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I want to obtain a string from a list view click,this list view is populate from a bbdd, i think this code is ok but don't work.

```
       //Creamos la instancia de DataBaseHelper, un cursor y aplicamos el metodo getNombres al cursor y llamamos al metodo encargado de gestioanr ese cursor
        ayudabbdd = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        Cursor nombresC;     
        nombresC = (Cursor) ayudabbdd.getNombres();  
        nombresC.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(nombresC);
        //Para crear un simpleCursorAdapter necesitamos
        //Contexto this
        //Layour donde se mostrara el resultado, generalmente un textview
        //Cursor 
        //Cual sera el campo que recibiremos de la BBDD
        //Donde tenemos que poner esa informacion, generalmente el ID correspondiente al        textvies del layour del segundo parametro
        String[] from = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.CNOMBRE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.nombreLugar};
        SimpleCursorAdapter lugares = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.entrada_lista, nombresC, from, to);
        setListAdapter(lugares);
        listanombres =  (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listanombres.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}


       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String nombreSelec;
                nombreSelec = (String) listanombres.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                Intent intent = new Intent(listatab.this, mostrarLugar.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombre", nombreSelec);
                startActivity(intent);


          }
```

Im making debug and nombreSelec value is `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41496db0`

Im trying this

```
String nombreClicks = nombresC.getString((int) arg3);
        intent.putExtra("nombre",nombreClicks);
        startActivity(intent);
```

bit it return me a exception

Comment: try this `listanombres.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString()`

Comment: Understanding your code is quite difficult as your comments (and a lot of the code) is in spanish (or some other language? I don't even know). I would advice you to provide an english version, as this would enable a broader audience to answer the question :)

Comment: in listview row only single textview set or custom listview set with multiple control in listview?

Comment: "try this listanombres.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString()" same result

Comment: Have you tried my answer.? What's the result for it..?

Comment: yes, i reply u in your answer

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
public class CheckData extends ListActivity  {     
  TextView selection;
  public int idToModify; 
  DataManipulator dm;
  List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  List<String[]> names2 =null ;
  String[] stg1;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.check);
     dm = new DataManipulator(this);
     names2 = dm.selectAll();
     stg1=new String[names2.size()]; 
     int x=0;
     String stg;
     for (String[] name : names2) {
            stg = name[1]+" – "+name[2]+ " – "+name[3]+" – "+name[4];
            stg1[x]=stg;
            x++;
     }
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stg1);
     this.setListAdapter(adapter);
     selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
}      
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     String nombreSelec = selection.setText(stg1[position]);
     Intent intent = new Intent(listatab.this, mostrarLugar.class);
     intent.putExtra("nombre", nombreSelec);
     startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

and check it from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8431438/964741

Comment: string return me "nombre", this string precedent from from = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.CNOMBRE}; where DataBaseHelper.CNOMBRE is "nombre", don't return me the value of the row, only the name

Comment: I don't know how i can implement this on my code, i understand the on create method, I'm new in java sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and let me know what happen,..

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lugares.getItem(arg2);
    String nombreSelec = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.CNOMBRE));

    Intent intent = new Intent(listatab.this, mostrarLugar.class);
    intent.putExtra("nombre", nombreSelec);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Look at this nice example [First list application](http://www.droidnova.com/first-list-application,37.html)

Comment: Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lugares.getItem(arg2);
 this line return me nullpointerexception

Comment: And what about this line  Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItem(arg2);
? Same? Check it..

Comment: The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type AdapterView<capture#1-of ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(listatab.this, mostrarLugar.class);


        String nombreClicks= nombresC.getString(nombresC.getColumnIndex("nombre"));
        intent.putExtra("nombre",nombreClicks);
        startActivity(intent);


  }
```

This is the solution